# Hidden C#applet

Tags: c#, java, html, applet

This is an interesting one exercise for us, i think. I attached a link to an [html page code](http://bpaste.net/show/RSCojz9ZfacZIViEpaS6/). In fact I'm interested in one C#applet. I don't see it one a page, i only can see a scope of this applet. One field marked like "!important" but not used. I'm sure that it is doing something, but it needs to activate.

how can i check this applet or see what is it doing?

```
#myID
        {
            /*height: 0px !important;*/
            height: 366px;
            width: 800px;
        }
        #hiddenContainer
        {
            width: 800px;
            position: relative;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
<div id="hiddenContainer"><object id="myID" classid="http:CSharpApplet.dll#CSharpApplet.RocketControl"></object></div>
```

Comment: Find a way to download it and then decompile using Reflector or dotPeek.

Comment: This line is a comment :D

Comment: I know, but i can uncomment it. I mean, if somebody put it there, so it is important. but maybe this is negative. This is not just a website, this is a task from information security.